# Searching for non-existent key in IndexedDB objectStore still returns as success

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

I'm trying to see whether an entry already exists in an objectStore. If the entry exists, I need to alter a few of its fields; if the entry does not exist, I need to add it.

Here's my query:

```
var db = html5rocks.indexedDB.db;
  var trans = db.transaction(["topics"], "readwrite");
  var store = trans.objectStore("topics");
  var findRequest = store.get(tHash);
findRequest.onsuccess = function(event){
  console.log("logging event");
  console.log(event);
  var cursor = event.target.result;
}
findRequest.onerror(e){
console.log(e);
}
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that the `findRequest.onsuccess` function always fires - even though it's impossible that the `get(tHash)` request is finding anything (By the way, the "topics" objectStore contains zero entries when I do this...).
I figured I'd use the `onsuccess` and `onerror` functions to tell if I needed to update an existing record or create a new one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does indexedDB objectStore.get call onsuccess even when the objectStore does not contain the object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447030/why-does-indexeddb-objectstore-get-call-onsuccess-even-when-the-objectstore-does)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly from the [horse's mouth](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-get-IDBRequest-any-key):

> `IDBObjectStore.get()` produces the same result if a record with the given key doesn't exist as when a record exists, but has undefined as value. If you need to tell the two situations apart, you can use `openCursor` with the same key. This will return a cursor with undefined as value if a record exists, or no cursor if no such record exists.

I think you want something like:

```
var cursorRequest = store.openCursor(tHash);
cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var cursor = event.result;
  if (cursor) {
    // entry exists
  } else {
    // entry doesn't exist
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a helpful, complete answer w/source!